# Methyl orange coordination compound chemistry

Tags: coordination-compounds

Methyl orange changes colors depending on the acidity or basicity of the solution. But I have read that it forms complexes with certain ions. Can anybody suggest any resource regarding the coordination complex-formation chemistry of methyl orange?

Comment: Methyl orange is a zwitterion at low pH and an anion at high pH; it's a model species for coordination chemistry with cyclodextrin, Google should reveal numerous papers about it. It's also a diazo compound; the Wikipedia entry on diazo compounds has a section on metal complexes.